# Will the following code execute every time I access a member?

Tags: c#, singleton, mef

I have the following code in a class library:

```
public class Manager
{
    private static readonly Manager instance = new Manager();

    public static IHelper Helper { get { return Manager.instance.helper; } }

    [Import(typeof(IHelper))]
    internal IHelper helper { get; set; }

    private Manager()
    {
        using (DirectoryCatalog catalog =new DirectoryCatalog(@"c:\Dev\Plugins"))
        {
            CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the above class to set custom user-interface settings at run-time, will the constructor run every time I access a member (will it scan the directory)?

An example call might be `lblMask.Text = Helper.SearchMask;`

Comment: When you don't know if the constructor is called, you can output a string from it to test :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory scanning only happens in the instance constructor. The instance constructor only happens when `new Manager()` is used (assuming nobody cheats with reflection), which only happens once, in the static field initializer.

So: no. It should only happen once - the first time per app-domain.

However, you could just stick in a break-point / some kind of output, and find out...

Comment: I'm still a little confused. This is my thinking. When I call something like `Helper.SearchMask`, I am thinking it is going to access `Manager.instance.helper` which is going to do `new Manager`.  I think I am having trouble understanding the order of instantiation here how static works in this scenario

Comment: @Xaisoft if you want the code to run each time you could change instance from a member to a property. `public static Manager Instance { get { return new Manager(); } }`

Answer (score 1):

When you access the `Manager` class **for the first time** (either an instance of it or its static methods and fields), the static constructor of `Manager` will run and initialize the `instance` field.
So the next time you access the `instance` field, it is initialized and won't run `new Manager()`.

In fact the C# compiler will automatically move the fields initializations to the class constructor. The following code

```
private static readonly Manager instance = new Manager();
```

will be converted to this:

```
private static readonly Manager instance;
static Manager()
{
    instance = new Manager();
}
```